# How to find the average over an area of center for a given radius

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matlab

I have an excel file which contains the lat and long values of the center of a Tropical Cyclone(TC). The excel file is as given below:

```
19.8  69.4
20    69
20.4  68.2
20.5  67.2
20.5  65.7
20.3  65
20.2  64.2
20.2  63.7
20.2  62.9
20.2  62.3
20.2  61.5
20.1  61
20.1 60.3
20    59.5
19.9  58.9
19.8  58.3
```

Also, I have an NC(NetCDF) file which is of that of air temperature(The link to the data is given)[air_temp.nc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H-QXY0-WVbKINaSz2qIQyJbtOoLhaADy/view?usp=sharing). Now what I intend to do is average over an area of radius 2.5◦ on the storm center for the variable in the NC data i.e. for each lat long value I need to find the average over an area of average 2.5◦. I know how to find the simple average using NumPy mean for individual lat-long, but I am confused about how to find over an area for a given radius.

Comment: you have a `latitude` and `longitude` in TC data and you have a `latitude` and `longitude` in NC data. You want to find out mean of what value ? What is the column name which contains values whose mean is to be found out ?

Comment: @Simple Guy, I need to find the mean of the variable present in the NC data. It will be named as airtemp

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not so much calculating the average, as it is to create a subset within a radius. Once you have that subset, calculating the average is trivial.

You find an example of subsetting on radius here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59060532/calculate-coordinates-inside-radius-at-each-time-point

Note however that that example works with a 2d circle, which isn't exactly what you are looking for because Earth is a globe. In order to adjust for it, you'll need the great circle distance (or Haversine distance). Why? Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

You'll find a python implementation of that concept here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889566/calculate-euclidean-distance-for-latitude-and-longitude-pandas-dataframe-pytho

## 1. Load the data into a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

data = xr.open_dataset('file')
df = data.to_dataframe()
```

Comment: @S van Balen thanks for the suggestion you have given. I have gone through both the examples but I am not able to interpret both as I am new in using python, so if you can help by showing how to use both in my problem it will be much appreciated...

Comment: Do you already have a data frame up an running with the values loaded? If so could you add it to the question. If you don't know how to do that, let me know!

Comment: @S van Balen I dont know how to do that. Can you please show how to do that

Comment: Ok I'll add it to my answer because comments don't allow enough formatting. Please comment further questions, I'll add them step by step.

Comment: @S van Balen ok values loaded. Now next what to do?

Comment: Ok I'm not going to dictate every step. Next I want you to group on lat (just lat for now), have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values and update you Q with it.

Comment: Ok lat is grouped

Answer (score 1):

**Define a function to calculate distance between two latitudes and longitudes.** I found php implementation of below [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1019/how-to-find-nearest-locations-from-a-collection-of-coordinates-latitude-and-longitude-with-php-mysql). I converted it to python.

```
import numpy as np 
import math 

def getDistanceBetweenPoints(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2):
        theta = longitude1 - longitude2
        distance = math.sin(np.radians(latitude1)) * math.sin(np.radians(latitude2)) + math.cos(np.radians(latitude1)) * math.cos(np.radians(latitude2)) * math.cos(np.radians(theta))

        distance = math.acos(distance)
        distance = np.degrees(distance)

        return distance
```

Import TC data in the pandas dataframe and apply below function to call on the DataFrame. The function would call above function `getDistanceBetweenPoints` for each latitude and longitude

```
# create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(tc_csv_file_path)

# take subset of the data frame with columns we want
df_lat_long = df[['latitude', 'longitude']]

# insert a new column in dataframe which would hold distance between the latitudes and longitudes
df_lat_long.insert(df_lat_long.shape[1], "distance", [0.0 for val in range(df_lat_long.shape[0])], True)
```

**Define a function which would be invoked row wise** on a data frame

```
def getDistanceBetweenPoints_df(row):
    # Place latitude/longitude for a centre point here
    # I have filled 0.0, you replace with with actual values
    centre_lat = 0.0
    centre_long = 0.0
    row['distance'] = getDistanceBetweenPoints(centre_lat, centre_long, row['longitude'], row['latitude'], unit='Km')
```

**Now invoke this function on data frame.** It will called row wise and it will populate the column `distance` in the dataframe with the distance between center latitude/longitude and the row's latitude/longitude

```
# Invoke function on dataframe
df_lat_long.agg(getDistanceBetweenPoints_df, axis='columns')

# View the dataframe for values only where distance is less than or equal to 2.5◦
df_lat_long[df_lat_long['distance'] <= 2.5]
```

So, these are the latitudes and longitudes where distance from the given centre is less than of equal to 2.5◦. Do whatever you want to do with these